# Saving Base64 String as .PNG not working

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-visualization

I have a base64 string that I got from using Google Charts.
The project is being written in Python/Django/Javascript if that helps.

```
chartStr = chart.getImageURI()
```

I want to save this string as a .png on my server.

I've tried

```
with open('foo.png',"wb") as f:
    f.write(chartStr.decode('base64'))
```

but I get an incorrect padding error. I fix this by adding a '=' at the end of the string chartStr. WHen I do that, the foo.png image is created but when I try to open it I get an error that says

**Fatal error reading PNG image file: Not a PNG file**

Any advice?
Thanks!

Comment: Does `getImageURI()` really return the image as a base64 encoded string?  Looks like it would return the image URI...

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean the image that the URI points to?

Comment: I get a string like 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0...' I can put that in my address bar and it will load the image without the '='

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't really know what I'm doing

Comment: Have you tried stripping the `data:image/png;base64,` from `chartStr` before saving it?

Comment: Because it is an encoded form of the address to the place the picture is actually located. Unless google has a very odd definition of URI.

Comment: How would I attack it then? The long term goal is to save these images and link them to models I have in the database

Comment: Use any number of the libraries that Python has to just follow the image uri and download it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you added the `=` to the string the returned string from `.decode("base64")`  was the same as the input string minus the appended `=`.

To write the `.png` to a file you need to do the following:

```
head, data = chartStr.split(",", 1)
with open('foo.png',"wb") as f:
     f.write(data.decode('base64'))
```

This removes the `data:image/png;base64,` stuff and leaves you with some base64 encoded data.